# JSF : how to display search results?

Tags: java, jsf

i want to implement a small search engine , i have index page where user enter search keyword then he redirected to search results page so how to display the search results since they are dynamically generated
i am using lucene and i have this page implemented in jsp (i want to redesign it in jsf) :

```
<p style=" color: green"> <%=Srchr.HitsCount() %> Searching result(s) for :  <%= SearchText %>
<p>------------------------------------------------------------------
<% for (int i = 0 ; i<Srchr.HitsCount() ; i++){ %>
     <p> <%= (i+1) %> : <a href=   <%= Srchr.getHits()[i]  %> > <%= Srchr.getHits()[i] %> </a>
```

where srchr is the searcher class that access lucene db.

please help me .

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. have your search button on the home page be

   ```
   <h:commandButton action="#{searchBean.search}" value="Search" />
   ```
2. Let the `public String search()` method fill the search results into a property of the bean (for example, `List<SearchResult>`)
3. Return `"searchResults"` from the method, which is defined as a navigation outcome in `faces-config.xml`, and forwards to the `searchResults.jsp`
4. Use `<h:dataTable value="#{searchBean.results} var="result"` to show the results